# How do I create a TMS WEB Core project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tms-web-core

I installed [TMS WEB Core](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tmssoftware.tmswebcore) as an extension in Visual Studio Code:

[image: TMS Web Core in Visual Studio Code]

But how do I start or create a new project for it now?

I don't see anything in the extension settings or in the menu at the top. Is there maybe a terminal command to create a project or how can I create a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I missed this item on the left-hand side:

[image: TMS Web Core Commands in Visual Studio Code]

The extension adds a "TMS Commands" button on the left side. From there you can click on "Create New Project":

[image: TMS Web Core in Visual Studio Code]

Then you just follow the steps and your project will be created.