# How do I open the form designer for TMS WEB Core in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, delphi, tms, tms-web-core

I downloaded the [TMS WEB Core extension on Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tmssoftware.tmswebcore) and I've [created a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77351078/2908017) for it:

[image: TMS Web Core project in Visual Studio Code]

But now the question is, how do I open the form designer as shown in the [extension overview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tmssoftware.tmswebcore) GIF:

[image: TMS Web Core in Visual Studio Code]

They have a `[Design]` view for the `Unit1.pas` file. I only see the code and I don't see a view to design the form visually.

How do I open the form designer or where can I find it?

---

When using TMS WEB Core in the Delphi IDE, I can simply press `F12` on my keyboard to switch between code and design, but this doesn't work on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I managed to find the form designer.

It turns out that my [`DelphiLSP` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EmbarcaderoTechnologies.delphilsp) was causing the form designer not to work.

As soon as I disabled my `DelphiLSP` extension, the form designer appeared and worked.

So it seems like you can't have `DelphiLSP` and `TMS WEB Core` enabled at the same time. Hopefully, this is just a bug and gets fixed in the future though.

---

Also pressing `F12` to switch between code and design doesn't work in Visual Studio Code, but `Ctrl+F12` does work.